# How can I force this method to return the next xml file name in the folder after it's contents change?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, file-io, delete-file

I'm getting my file names, randomly I believe, but getting them with this.

```
public static string getXMLrequestFileNames()
{
    string path = requestsFolder;
    fileName = "";

    int count = 0;

    foreach (string s in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.xml").Select(Path.GetFileName))
    {
        fileName = "\\" + s;
        count++;
    }
    return fileName;
}
```

I place the file name in a `string` and hold it for deletion. When I delete the file with the following code, I'm still seeing the last file name from above.

```
private static void deleteRequest()
{
    string curFileWeekDelete = (filename);
    bool test = false;

    if (File.Exists(requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete))
    {
        string[] getAppPaths = Directory.GetFiles(requestsFolder);

        test = getAppPaths.Contains(requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete);
        foreach (string getAppPath in getAppPaths)
            if (test == true)
            {
                File.Delete(requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete);
                //filename = "";
            }
    }
}
```

Once the file is deleted I run through `getXMLrequestFileNames()` again. The next file loads appropriately but the file name being found is the deleted file name?!

Comment: Why do you only return the last fileName?

Comment: What do you mean by `The next file loads appropriately...`. Nothing is loaded.

Comment: @Vajura I only load one file at a time. The approver either `bApprove` or `bDeny` the request. Then the file is deleted immediately. I don't want to load them all into memory or the form. Just one at a time. Randomly is ok, but maybe that's my problem??

Comment: Don't do `requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete`, use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Sjips Thank you for your response. The files load appropriately with that function being called by other functions in my logic file. The only thing this is used for is to get the file name and file extension for processing later.

Comment: @BCdotNET Yes. Correct. I'm a newb and I right my code for a while and then fall back and clean it up. I'm just starting to learn this. Thank You for reminding me. Better mental health to say `"HeLLo WorLDD" now for understanding and then make it pretty. :-D

Comment: What's the point of `int count`? Why loop through `Directory.GetFiles` when you only use the last result? Why is `fileName` a global field? Why all the shenanigans with `getAppPaths` -- don't you trust `File.Exists`?

Comment: `File.Delete(requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete);` is probably not okay. Path separator might be missing. For example your are trying to delete `C:\MyFolderMyFile.xml` instead of `C:\MyFolder\MyFile.xml`.

Comment: @BCdotNET As to `int count`. Saw that after I got my first response. It's worthless. :-( And actually the more I look at your references it seems that code might be the answer to `getXMLrequestFileNames()`

Comment: `File.Delete(requestsFolder + curFileWeekDelete);` is executed multiple times in your loop but there is no dependency with a loop variable. You can leave `foreach (string getAppPath in getAppPaths)` loop out.

Comment: @Sjips `curFileWeekDelete` should be formatted by `getXMLrequestFileNames()` when I `return filename` shown above. Is that not the correct syntax? I did notice in a messsageBox that the file name was preceeded by a \ ?? Does tat have something to do with it?

Comment: @Sjips I took Martins advice below on the `deleteRequest`. Much cleaner and seems to work. Thank You for helping me. I appreciate it Sjips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see many errors in your code:

whats the point of `count` variable? you are not using it anywhere

Consider using input parameters rather than using some magic global variables like:

```
string path = requestsFolder;
```

delete request can be changed to:

```
private static void deleteRequest()
    {
        if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(requestsFolder + filename)))
        {    
            File.Delete(Path.Combine(requestsFolder + filename));
        }
}
```

getXMLrequestFileNames() returns only last found file not all file names, consider:

```
 public static string[] getXMLrequestFileNames()
    {

       return Directory.GetFiles(requestsFolder, "*.xml").Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. The code is written the way it is to determine if in fact the file still exists (in the event that in the future I accidently add a button to allow multiple deletions here). After testing that the file still exists I send the delete to a messageBox with a yes/no case switch. As to `count` uhh... Yeah. Noticed that as soon as got the first response. It's worthless. :-(

Comment: If you want to check if particular file exist use only File.Exist(path to file) - if it return true you can show message box and after yes - you will call File.Delete(path to file) no need to create separate methods for that

Comment: That makes sense. Hmmm... Processing.... I actually don't code for my real job, but I always comment back. I'll try it. Thank You Martin!! :-D

Comment: Well that definitely still deletes the first file. The next file in the folder (a new file from the folder) is loaded correctly, but it does not show as being a new file. That's where my problem is. Thank You for helping me shorten the code. :-D I appreciate it Martin.

Comment: Checking your edits Martin. I'm gonna have to rewrite a lot of sh**. :-( Processing.

Comment: Well it definitely works. I had to modify it some. I'll post it later. But it really didn't solve my question. Thanks for your help Martin!! I appreciate it. I'll add edit's to my post. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok. I'm hoping you might still be listening. I missed the answer in your very first... Third sentence. I moved the global variable on the 'ApproveTimeForm' to only the absolute required locations being called at 'bApprove` and `bDeny`. Now I have another issue with my `getXMLrequestFileNames()` returning an error if there are no files. Thank You Martin. Brilliant!! :-D

Comment: it should return you empty string array if there are no files. It will throw an exception only when requestsFolder does not exist

Comment: That's what I found. I used this with a dialog box. if (filename == "")
            {
                dr = MessageBox.Show
                switch (dr)
                {
                    case DialogResult.Yes:
                        ApproveTime.ActiveForm.Close();
                        break;

                    case DialogResult.No:
                        break;
                }  That closes the form finally. :-D